# Swift UILabel with horizontal lines on both sides

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uilabel

I am trying to create a UILabel that has 2 horizontal lines on the left and right side like this:

[image]

Does anyone know the best approach for doing this in Swift? The content text in the center will change so I want to make sure it can adapt. I'd really like to create some kind of reusable UIView class but I'm not sure where to start?

Thank you!

Comment: create a uiview subclass. add 2 subview for lines and a uilabel. set CGRect's for your purpose.

Comment: Are you using storyboards? Are the lines fixed width? Or is been done programmatically?

Answer (score 3):

You can take two `UIview` of height `1 or 2` pixels of both side of the label. so it's look likes line!!

And you should set background color to black of that view!

Hope this will help :)

Comment: + center vertically + horizontal spacing to UIlabel

Comment: @simpleBob : Yeah required to set appropriate constraint

Answer (score 1):

Take one `UIView` with height of 2. Set `leading & Trailing` according to `Super View`.

Now take one `UILabel` with background color white and put `Vertically Center` to line view.

Make both `Center` same.

Your work done.

For more help please refer below image.

[image]

Comment: How would this work if the text changes? I want it to be dynamic.

Comment: Just increase `UILable Width` as it text increase.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an extension on UILabel

```
public extension UILabel {
    func drawLineOnBothSides(labelWidth: CGFloat, color: UIColor) {

        let fontAttributes = [NSFontAttributeName: self.font]
        let size = self.text?.size(attributes: fontAttributes)
        let widthOfString = size!.width

        let width = CGFloat(1)

        let leftLine = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: self.frame.height/2 - width/2, width: labelWidth/2 - widthOfString/2 - 10, height: width))
        leftLine.backgroundColor = color
        self.addSubview(leftLine)

        let rightLine = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: labelWidth/2 + widthOfString/2 + 10, y: self.frame.height/2 - width/2, width: labelWidth/2 - widthOfString/2 - 10, height: width))
        rightLine.backgroundColor = color
        self.addSubview(rightLine)
    }
}
```

This will add a horizontal line of width of 1.0 on the both side of your label. If you don't add text for your label, it will show two horizontal lines through center with some spaces in between them.

Answer (score 1):

As others have mentioned, you can achieve this using three views:

[image: example image]

Add a View to your scene to use as a container. I called this view "Lined Label Holder."

To that container, add two Views, one to produce the line on either side of the label.

Add the label in between the two views, and give it some text. Due to the "height = Test.height" constraint on the Lined Label Holder, The intrinsic  height of this label is used to calculate the container's height.

The label is allowed to grow with added text and the lines will always start 5px away from the edges of the text and extended to the edges of the container, whose width can be set independently.

This image shows the required constraints:

[image: constraints]

Answer (score 0):

Use one UIView with black background and height of 1px, set label background to white, align its text to center and align UILabel to center of UIView (there is no need for 2 views since label white background will cover UIView).

Answer (score 0):

Not necessary 2 UIView's.

Take **1 UIView** and give background **black** color.Add the constraints necessary with: **height=2**.

place 1 label on the center and give required constraints